# requesting a webpage and not returning the same html

Tags: c#, .net, http

I'm using `System.Net.Http` to return a webpage. Compared to the actual login page I can't figure out why it's not returning the login table I need.

```
 var loginUrl = "https://prowand.pro-unlimited.com/login.html";
 CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
 HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
 handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
 //login
 var resp1 = await client.GetAsync(loginUrl);
 var content1 = await resp1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

It doesn't return the same information. Is it because of JavaScript?

[image]

Comment: It's possible the page was expected a user agent string. Try adding one to your request and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a User Agent String to your client.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

// User Agent String header
// Can be a different user agent if you like, your choice
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36");

var resp1 = await client.GetAsync(loginUrl);
var content1 = await resp1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The User Agent String tells the website that you're a particular browser. It's often used by the website to determine how to layout the page. In this case when this page detects no string it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

The login window is in following html which is not a script

```
                <label class='block' style='margin-top:55px;'>Username</label>
                <input id="usernamefield" name="username" class="block full-width" type="text" autocomplete="off" htmlEscape="true"> 

                <label class='block m-t-xl'>Password</label>
                <input id="passwordfield" class="block full-width m-b-sm" name="password" type="password" autocomplete="off" htmlEscape="true"> 

                <a href='/login_help.html'>Need Help?</a>

                <button type='submit' name="loginButton" class='btn btn-success m-t-xl p-t-md floatright'>Log in</button>
```